# How to split characters in an array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, character

I have an array like this :

```
var a = ["ABC", "DEF", "HIJKL"];
```

and I want to read all of array in a loop and every time , split each of character and keep their position . like this :

```
A=1,1
B=1,2
C=1,3
D=2,1
E=2,2
F=2,3
.
.
.
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to traverse through the elements in array and looping for each character in it works like charm.

Code :

```
var a = ["ABC", "DEF", "HIJKL"];

a.map((item,index)=>{

    for(i=0;i<item.length;i++)
  {
    console.log(item[i]+" = ",index+1,i+1);
  }
})
```

Output :

```
A =  1 1
B =  1 2
C =  1 3
D =  2 1
E =  2 2
F =  2 3
H =  3 1
I =  3 2
J =  3 3
K =  3 4
L =  3 5
```

```js
var a = ["ABC", "DEF", "HIJKL"];

a.map((item,index)=>{

    for(i=0;i<item.length;i++)
  {
    console.log(item[i]+" = ",index+1,i+1);
  }
})
```

Hope it helps..!
Thank you.

~ Praz

Comment: Thank you buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array and in loop split every item and then loop through result.

```js
var arr = ["ABC", "DEF", "HIJKL"];
arr.forEach((val, i) => {
  val.split('').forEach((val2, j) => {
    console.log(`${val2}=${i+1},${j+1}`)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is displayed with `console`. But you can put it in a variable, depending on what you want.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
     console.log(a[i].charAt(j) + i + "," + j);
    }   
}
```

Comment: what do you think is `a[i,j]`? It's valid JS but it's most likely not what you think it is. And why do you `.toString()` a string? `charAt()` can not return anything but a string. And `alert()` is an bad utility, better use the `console` to debug/log/etc.

Comment: a[i,j] is the position in the array at run time of the loop. i & j are the counters of the for-loop, this is as basic JS as it can get.

Comment: `a[i,j] === a[j]`

Comment: I edited my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used classic coding style. please check

```js
var a = ["ABC", "DEF", "HIJKL"];

for(var i=0; i< a.length ; i++)
{
     for(var y=0; y < a[i].length ; y++)
    {
        console.log(`${a[i][y]} = ${i+1},${y+1}`) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy.

Comment: If you believe that this answer is helpfull, please consider to upvote or consider to accept it as anwer. thank you

Comment: ok @Simonare but my reputation is 13 and I need 2 more :)

Comment: now it is 18 :)  regards